# Trying to apply multi-processing to a function that processes xml to csv

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to process ~477,000 XML files to csv using a library called irsx. The process is taking ages, so I am attempting to find ways to speed it up. Does anyone know how I can effectively apply multi-processing to this function and utilize all my computer's cores?

I have tried creating a pool and using `.apply_async()` but it didn't work as expected.

```
import os
from irsx.xmlrunner import XMLRunner
import pandas as pd
import time
import flatdict
from collections import defaultdict
import multiprocessing as mp
import glob

Frames1 = pd.DataFrame()

directory = "/Users/upmetrics/Desktop/990ALLXML/"    

def listdir_nohidden(path):
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if not f.startswith('.'):
            yield f

myfiles = list(listdir_nohidden(directory))

listfiles = len([str(file) for file in listdir_nohidden(directory)])

dataframes = {}

mydict = {}

def Process():

    current_file = 1

    for file in listdir_nohidden(directory):
        # Get just the id of the 990 record from the file name
        record_id = file.split('_')[0]
        parsed_filing = XMLRunner().run_filing(record_id)

        progress = (current_file / listfiles) * 100

        if current_file % 100 == 0:
            print(("{}% Complete!").format(round(progress,2)))
            print(("{} out of {} processed.").format(current_file, listfiles))

        for sked in parsed_filing.get_result():
            fields = flatdict.FlatterDict(sked['schedule_parts'], delimiter=":")
            dictionary_of_fields = defaultdict(list)

            for key, value in fields.items():
                dictionary_of_fields[key].append(value)

            if sked['schedule_name'] in dataframes.keys():
                # Add new data to an existing section
                current_frame = dataframes[sked['schedule_name']]
                new_frame = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(dictionary_of_fields)
                updated_frame = pd.concat([current_frame, new_frame], join='outer', sort=True, ignore_index=True)
                dataframes[sked['schedule_name']] = updated_frame
            else:
                # This section hasn't been seen yet - create it
                dataframes[sked['schedule_name']] = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(dictionary_of_fields)  


        current_file += 1

    return dataframes
```

Comment: Your code does not show how you are running the code using a pool of processes. Also, have you looked at where the time is spent? What needs to be sped up/parallelized? Is it the call to `.run_filing()` or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

For such a job I would use `Pool.imap_unordered`.
Basically, because it starts yielding results as soon as they are available.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import base64

def worker(path):
    # Generate random output file name
    tmpname = base64.b64encode(os.urandom(12), b'__').decode() + '.csv'
    with open(path) as f:
        data = f.read()
    # << process your data here, put csv formatted data in csvdata.... >>
    with open(tmpname, 'w') as f:
         f.write(csvdata)
    return {'source': path, 'result': tmpname}

# Generate your list of filenames "myfiles" here.

p = mp.Pool()
for rv in p.imap_unordered(worker, myfiles):
    print('Processed: ', rv['source'])
    # Append the data from rv['result'] to a master csv file...
```

**Edit**: So why have each worker write to a file? You have a *lot* of data files. My assumption is that these each contain a significant amount of data.

You could have the worker *return* that data. But then the worker process would have to transfer that data back to the parent process. This is done using a `SimpleQueue`, if I read the source code correctly. It involves pickling the data in the worker process and unpickling in the parent process. Deep down it uses named pipes on ms-windows, and sockets on other systems.
These transfer mechanisms use small buffer sizes of 8192 bytes.

If OTOH, you use `mmap` to write and concatenate the data, most of it would still be in the OS's buffer cache from the write in the worker when you read/write it in the parent.

Obviously you'd have to run tests to determine which one is faster. A lot depends on the size of the data from the individual files.

Comment: Thank you Roland, however, I think I may have miscommunicated my intention here. My aim is to have all of these files on one csv, with a new row per file.

Comment: @OttoThornton-Silver I *explicitly* did it this way because I *expect* it to be faster. I'll edit my answer to expand on the why; that doesn't belong in a comment.